# pgr_dijkstra returns an empty set

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I'm trying to write a function that is able to find the shortest way between two points using `pgr_dijkstra` function. I'm following [this](https://blog.daftcode.pl/find-your-way-with-the-power-of-postgis-pgrouting-66d620ef201b) guide. With data provided in the guide everything works fine. But when I try to apply the same steps (build a topology using `pgr_createTopology` and then test it with `pgr_dijkstra`) to another [data set](https://data.nextgis.com/en/region/RU-KDA/), `pgr_dijkstra` returns an empty result. I've also noticed that the guide's data set has a `LineString` geometry column, while I have a `MultiLineString` geometry column. What could be the reason?

My table's structure:

```
                                        Table "public.roads"
 Column |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------  
 id     | integer                        |           | not null | nextval('roads_gid_seq'::regclass)
 geom   | geometry(MultiLineString,4326) |           |          |
 source | integer                        |           |          |
 target | integer                        |           |          |
Indexes:
    "roads_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "roads_geom_idx" gist (geom)
    "roads_source_idx" btree (source)
    "roads_target_idx" btree (target)
```

Topology creation query:

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('roads', 0.00001, 'geom', 'id');
```

Shortest way test:

```
SELECT seq, node, edge, cost as cost, agg_cost, geom
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
   'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom, true) AS cost FROM roads',
   -- Some random points
   1, 200
) AS pt
JOIN roads rd ON pt.edge = rd.id;
```

Comment: What error are you getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually related to geometry data types. The function doesn't work properly with `MultiLineString`, though it doesn't produce any errors. So, I've converted `MultiLineString` to `LineString` and now everything seems to be OK.